# Setting fields on a exception while complying with CA 1032

Tags: c#, code-analysis

CA1032 says each exception must have the following constructors:

```
public NewException()
public NewException(string)
public NewException(string, Exception)
protected or private NewException(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)
```

However, in this case I want to capture some `ExceptionContext` which has some more information. Currently my code looks like this:

```
public class NewException : Exception {
  public NewException(ExceptionContext context) 
    : base() {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    this.context = context;
  }
}
```

How do I ensure that an `ExceptionContext` is set on the `NewException` while still complying with CA1032?

I could set the context in a property:

```
public class NewException : Exception {
  public ExceptionContext Context { get { /*get*/ } set { /*null check and set*/ } }
  /*Standard constructors...*/
}
```

but now the is no way to make a caller set a `ExceptionContext`, the class is more verbose because I have to have a backing variable (or no null check on the property), and `NewException` is mutable.

I notice the "When to suppress" section says:

> It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule when the violation is caused by using a different access level for the public constructors.

I am not quite sure what is meant by this. Is this saying that I am allowed to write something like this, and then suppress the analysis?

```
public class NewException : Exception {
  public NewException(ExceptionContext context) 
    : this() {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    this.context = context;
  }

  private NewException() 
    : base() { }

  public NewException(ExceptionContext context, string message) 
    : this(message) {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    this.context = context;
  }

  private NewException(string message) 
    : base(message) { }
  ...
}
```

**Edit/additional question:** Do I need to implement `NewException(ExceptionContext, SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)` or is the point of the `SerializationInfo` to store other state?

```
protected NewException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
  : base (info, context) {
  this.context = new ExceptionContext();
  this.context.Field1 = (T1)info.GetValue("Field1", typeof(T1));
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic behind that rule is that there should be a standard way to construct exception objects. (I'll admit I don't understand the purpose of that logic, but that's not relevant here.) There may also be additional ways specific to your exception classes, but the standard ways should always work.

In your case, if you want to construct a `NewException` object but don't have any `ExceptionContext` to pass, what do you want your `NewException` object to do?

If you want to disallow that, then you don't want your exception objects to behave like standard exception objects, and should disable any warnings about that fact.

If you want to allow that, then you need to provide the standard constructor overloads, and do whatever seems best for your specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

As you have custom situation, (in my opinion) you should probably suppress this warning. To feel consistent with requirements, you can still use this set of constructors:

```
public NewException(ExceptionContext)
public NewException(ExceptionContext, string)
public NewException(ExceptionContext, string, Exception)
protected or private NewException(ExceptionContext, SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "you **should** suppress this warning"? Where have you got that from?

Comment: @Jonny, I've got it from my head.. hence I've edited my answer a little.